# Is string::size_type really big enough to hold any string?

Tags: c++, string, size-type

I browsed through some threads about `string::size_type` here and I do understand according to C++ standards that this `size_type` guarantees enough allocation for all string usage.

I just find that hard to believe. What if I put the whole text of say *C++ Primer 4th edition* into a string? Or worse, what if I put infinite characters into a string? I just don't see how it can handle that.

Comment: A program that tries to put an infinite number of characters into a string crashes with error code 42.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string::size_type` is guaranteed to be large enough for all strings *that the current implementation supports* - not any string of any size. If your implementation supports strings up to e.g. 8 GB, `size_type` can contain numbers up to 8 billion.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't guarantee enough allocation for *all string usage*. Quite the opposite: it limits the maximum length of a `std::string`. Basically, it is the type that is used by the string implementation to hold its own length. This limitation is a bit artificial: usually, `size_type` is large enough to hold an offset as large as the address space of the process - which of course can't be reached since you can never dedicate your entire address space to a single string.

(you actually *can* put the whole text of C++ Primer into a string.)